# Read .trc file line by line and return information using python

Tags: python

I need some help with the python code to read .trc file line by line and return the data from the line read.

The trc file example:

```
<A> DATA1 </A>
<L size ="20">
  <F4 size ="1">46.0</F4> 
  <F4 size ="1">47.1</F4>  
  <F4 size ="1">23.0</F4> 
  <F4 size ="1">17.45</F4> 
  <F4 size ="1">49.0</F4> 
  <F4 size ="1">50.0</F4>       
  <F4 size ="1">12.0</F4>    
</L>
<A> DATA2 </A>
<L size ="20">
  <F4 size ="1">12.0</F4> 
  <F4 size ="1">19.34</F4>  
  <F4 size ="1">23.0</F4> 
  <F4 size ="1">99.0</F4> 
  <F4 size ="1">0.11</F4> 
  <F4 size ="1">78.0</F4>       
  <F4 size ="1">12.0</F4>  
</L>
```

The output should be write inside the excel table

Output expected:

```
DATA        DATA2
46.0        12.0
47.1        19.34
23.0        23.0
17.45       99.0
49.0        0.11
50.0        78.0
12.0        12.0
```

I am new to python, hope anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Use any of the XML parser?

Comment: Can you give any example on XML parser tool ? @SMA

Comment: Multiple examples online - e.g. [this one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/xml-parsing-python/)

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict

trc = '''<r><A> DATA1 </A>
<L size ="20">
  <F4 size ="1">46.0</F4> 
  <F4 size ="1">47.1</F4>  
  <F4 size ="1">23.0</F4> 
  <F4 size ="1">17.45</F4> 
  <F4 size ="1">49.0</F4> 
  <F4 size ="1">50.0</F4>       
  <F4 size ="1">12.0</F4>    
</L>
<A> DATA2 </A>
<L size ="20">
  <F4 size ="1">12.0</F4> 
  <F4 size ="1">19.34</F4>  
  <F4 size ="1">23.0</F4> 
  <F4 size ="1">99.0</F4> 
  <F4 size ="1">0.11</F4> 
  <F4 size ="1">78.0</F4>       
  <F4 size ="1">12.0</F4>  
</L></r>'''

root = ET.fromstring(trc)
data = defaultdict(list)
l_list = root.findall('.//L')
for idx,l in enumerate(l_list,1):
  key = 'DATA{}'.format(idx)
  for f in l.findall('.//F4'):
    data[key].append(f.text)
print('\t'.join(data.keys()))
for row in zip(*data.values()):
  print('\t'.join(str(v) for v in row))
```

output

```
DATA1   DATA2
46.0    12.0
47.1    19.34
23.0    23.0
17.45   99.0
49.0    0.11
50.0    78.0
12.0    12.0
```